# Doctrine ODM with Symfony, embedded documents

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine

I've got two documents, one called Gigs, one called Tracks. Tracks should be embedded docs on Gigs, but I can't seem to get it working. I've followed several tutorials and can't quite get there.

Gig entity

```
<?php 

namespace IGIG\GigBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document(repositoryClass="IGIG\GigBundle\Document\GigRepository")
 */
class Gig
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\EmbedMany(targetDocument="Track")
     */
    private $tracks = array();

    /**
     * Gets the value of tracks.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTracks()
    {
        return $this->tracks;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of tracks.
     *
     * @param mixed $tracks the tracks
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setTracks($tracks)
    {
        $this->tracks = $tracks;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Track entity

```
<?php 

namespace IGIG\GigBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\EmbeddedDocument()
 */
class Track
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * Gets the value of id.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of id.
     *
     * @param mixed $id the id
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of title.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of title.
     *
     * @param mixed $title the title
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I removed all the irrelevant fields just to demonstrate the relationship. However when I call the embedded documents in my controller/view, I get nothing?

The function in my controller:

```
public function selectTracksAction($id)
    {
        $gig = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')
                    ->getManager()
                    ->getRepository('IGIGGigBundle:Gig')
                    ->findOneById($id);

        return $this->render('IGIGPaymentGatewayBundle:Store:selectTracksPerGig.html.twig', array(
            'gig' => $gig,
        ));
    }
```

And the logic in my view (in Twig):

```
{% for track in gig.tracks %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ track.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ track.price }}</td>
        <td><input name="{{ track.id }}" type="checkbox"></td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I've tried ArrayCollection, but didn't get far with that, and a few other ways, but I'm pretty confused. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you examine the raw document from the MongoDB shell, what data is contained within? I reproduced your model in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jmikola/a62cea4d5865369d8d3e) and it works as I would expect. You are correct that ArrayCollection is preferable, but I tested with a plain PHP array and that worked fine as well.

Comment: Also, can you confirm if Twig is able to access other properties of `gig` and that only `gig.tracks` is an issue? Based on its [rules](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#variables) for property access, I would imagine it'd immediately invoke `getTracks()` since `$tracks` is declared private, but it'd be good to verify that's the case anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make 'one to many' or 'many to many' mapping if u want to many tracks in one gigs and also you should do form embedding and for it u may follow the link : [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)

Comment: There's not such annotation as OneToMany or ManyToMany, they're supposed to be embedded documents. EmbedMany does exist, however. I think you're thinking of relational data, not embedded?